# Bolts don't fit for Stronglight ring on Athena 11s

Tags: chainring, campagnolo

I wanted to replace my ring on my Athena 11s Compact Crank (from 2014) and bought a Stronglight Ring (CT2 Road, Campagnolo 11s, 5-Arm, 110mmBCD).

Unfortunately the Ring Bolts are one or two milimeters too long, hence the rings dangle.

Any idea what chain ring bolts i need to buy or how i can find out? I only found the Super Record ones and no information about compatibility.

**Update:**

I found a note on some Stronglight rings that for athena cranks from before 2011 you need the FC-SR200 bolts for 5-arm cranks post 2011.

I bought the campagnolo version but they are exactly the same i already have on my crank. I would need narrower ones but i can't find any.

Comment: Too wide how?  Do the bolts simply not fit through the holes, or do they have shoulders that prevent them from going all the way through and seating tightly against the ring?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Sorry, i ment long not wide (english is not my first language). They are too long and thus the rings are not tight.

Comment: If it is simply that the new rings are thinner and hence "shoulders" on the bolts prevent the heads from pressing tightly against the ring, a "hack" would be to install some appropriately-sized washers.  You'd probably want them on placed on the bolts first, against the bolt heads, vs between the ring and spider.  Or, alternatively, against the nut heads.  Of course finding such washers could be a challenge, though a clever person could probably drill out ones of a different size.

Comment: I actually tried the washer solution when I built a fixie on budget. It wasn't really a challenge, I just measured the bolts, went to nearest hardware store and bought washers. If measuring is too difficult, you can always take the bolt with you and try different washers until one fits.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely shorter chainring bolts available, I don't know if campagnolo makes the correct size (2mm shorter than your current one's) though.

You could try to grind or file down the female part of each chainring bolt by approximately 2mm. This wil enable you to screw in the male part of the chainringbolt further which will enable you to correctly clamp the chainring(s) to the cranck arm. You might need to clean up the threads in order for the male/female parts of the bolts to easily thread into eachother.

You could alternatively use something like this: https://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=59276
I have seen similar spacers on an old shimano 600 cranckset.

there are also so called 'chainline spacers':
https://wickwerks.com/products/1x-chainline-spacers/
The same effect could be achieved with appropriately sized washers though (which will be a cheaper option).

You can choose from various chainring bolt lengths on this website:
https://www.benscycle.com/chainring-bolts/search

Cheaper chainring bolts in multiple lengths:
https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/1pc-sport-Mountain-Bicycle-Crankset-Screws-Nut-For-Bolts-Chainring-Wheel-screw-Crankset-bolts-Nut-For/32479905496.html

PS: iirc you only need to replace the 'female' (threads on the inside) part of the chainring bolts with a shorter version, you could potentially keep using the original campagnolo 'male' parts which might be desireable such that you keep the campagnolo branding on your chainring bolts. Using the original (longer) 'male' parts will however make the thread stick out approx 2mm on the back of the inner chainring (when not using shims/spacers/washers).

If you could measure the thread length on the chainring bolts you currently have I could find you some suitable (2mm shorter) chainring bolts.

I hope this helps.